# The set of zeros of some polynomial over the closure of a finite field constitute a field in its own right

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $n$ be a positive integer and let $p(x) = x^{p^n} - x$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.  Let $Q$ be the set of all zeros of $p(x)$ over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Verify that this set is indeed a field.

Since this set is clearly a subset of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, I need to verify that it is a subfield.  So I need to show 3 things:

1. $Q$ is non-empty (which is true since $0$ clearly is in $Q$)
2. $Q$ is an additive group.
3. $Q\setminus \{0\}$ is a multiplicative group.

To show points 2 and 3 I basically need to assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $p(x)$ and then show that $\alpha - \beta$ and $\alpha\beta^{-1}$ are as well, but here I run into what looks like a very unpleasant application of the binomial expansion theorem.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Keep in mind that you are doing the binomial expansion modulo p. This should cause a lot of terms to vanish.

Comment: @jwsiegel True, I didn't realize this.

Comment: If $F$ is a field of characteristic $p > 0$, then $(a + b)^{p^k} = a^{p^k} + b^{p^k}$ for all $a,b \in F$ and all $k \geq 0$.

Comment: @Ethan Alwaise, The characteristic is inherited from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ correct?  Also, would I have to show that the element $1$ is in it or is it sufficient to show that my set is closed under taking multiplicative inverses?

Comment: Yes the characteristic is inherited. If you show $ab \in Q$ for all $a,b \in Q$ and $a^{-1} \in Q$ for all $a \in Q \setminus \{0\}$, then this implies that $1 \in Q$.

Comment: I got a little stuck on the multiplication part.  If I have $\alpha^{p^n}\beta^{p^n} - (\alpha \beta)$ how can I make that equal $(\alpha^{p^n} - \alpha)(\beta^{p^n} - \beta)$?  Or is that not the best approach?  I tried adding and subtracting something or introducing a factor that I know is $0$ but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: @Nino, try adding and subtracting $\alpha^{p^n}\beta$ This will lead to $0 + 0$